# Как правильно работать с транзакциями в MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Запустил 3 запрос на обновление 3-ех разных таблиц и обернул в Begin Tran и Commit Tran.

На втором запросе получил ошибку, но данные в первой таблице не откатились.

Разве не должен был быть откат?

**UPD**

Как я понимаю, я должен был использовать вместо

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 2
UPDARE 3
COMMIT TRAN
```

Вот это

```
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE 1
    UPDATE 2
    UPDARE 3
if @error<>0
    rollback tran
    COMMIT TRAN
```

?

Если это так, то статься на MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190295.aspx

Вводит в заблуждение, так не показан пример с проверкой на ошибки...

Еще не понял вот такого поведения:

Делал такой эксперимент:
Сначала делаю N раз вот этот запрос:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO ttt VALUES  (GETDATE())
```

--Транзакцию специально не закомитил

Затем отдельно делаю:

```
COMMIT TRAN
```

Затем

```
ROLLBACK tran
```

У меня откатились все мои N инсертов, хотя я сделал COMMIT TRAN, а лишь потом ROLLBACK tran.  По идее транзакция должна была завершиться и на откат ничего не должно было пойти...

Comment: Если три обновления в одной общей транзакции - должен, каждое в своей транзакции - нет. Хмм... а `rollback` то вызвали? Откат при `rollback` происходит, либо если не было `commit` - при завершении соединения.

Comment: @i-one А его нужно явно вызывать? Мне казалось, что он автоматически вызываться должен...

Comment: Да, если нужен откат, то нужно явно вызвать `rollback`. Однако, если если не было `commit` и `rollback` не был вызван, то откат произойдёт автоматически при закрытии соединения.

Comment: @i-one,А можно в ответ пример правильного использования? Мне всегда казалось, что BEGIN TRAN серия запросов COMMIN TRAN гарантируют, что если будет косяк, то будет откат...

Comment: Ах да, ещё при `xact_abort on`, но он не все ошибки откатывает. Сейчас составлю примеров.

Comment: При _"Сначала делаю N раз вот этот запрос"_ открываются вложенные транзакции, последующий `commit` уменьшает уровень вложенности на 1, а последующий `rollback` откатывает _все_ уровни.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вам стоит задавать новые вопросы в виде новых вопросов. "Еще не понял вот такого поведения:" имеет довольно слабое отношение к первой части вопроса.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В случае конструкции

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 2 --error
UPDATE 3
COMMIT TRAN
```

(при выполнении команд не в блоке `TRY ... CATCH ...`) если на втором `UPDATE` возникнет ошибка, исполнение команд может продолжиться и дойти до `COMMIT`.

Использование варианта

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 2
UPDATE 3
IF @@ERROR <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
ELSE
    COMMIT TRAN
```

не будет правильным, т.к. глобальная переменная `@@ERROR` содержит номер ошибки для последней исполненной команды. Это означает следующее: если `UPDATE 1` или `UPDATE 2` завершится с обшибкой, а `UPDATE 3` - без ошибки, то после `UPDATE 3` значение переменной `@@ERROR` станет равно `0`, что сделает ложным вывод об успешности всей транзакции.

Если нужно при ошибке делать откат, то тут могут быть два варианта.

Первый - это исполнение команд в блоке `TRY ... CATCH ...`

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE 1
    UPDATE 2 --error
    UPDATE 3
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

В этом случае, при возникновении ошибки на 2м шаге, исполнение не продолжится, а по-возможности перейдёт в блок `CATCH`, где можно принудительно вызвать `ROLLBACK`.

Второй вариант - включение опции `XACT_ABORT` перед входом в транзакцию.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 2 --error
UPDATE 3
COMMIT TRAN
```

В этом случае при возникновении ошибок (определённого рода, не любых) на 2-м `UPDATE` выполнение команд будет прервано и произойдёт автоматический откат изменений. (Может быть даже не стоит считать этот вариант самостоятельным, на мой взгляд включение `XACT_ABORT` - это некое дополнительное средство; не припомню случая, когда бы я для отката транзакции пользовался этой опцией обособленно).

В некоторых случаях используется и то и другое.

Ниже чуть подробнее об автоматическом и управляемом откате.

---

**Автоматический ROLLBACK**

`ROLLBACK` может происходить автоматически, при закрытии соединения, если для данного соединения есть незавершенные транзакции. Т.е. создали, например, таблицу

```
create table test (id int primary key);
```

Открываем соединение и в нём выполняем

```
begin tran;
insert into test (id) values (1);
select * from test;
```

закрываем соединение, не завершив транзакцию (ни `COMMIT`, ни `ROLLBACK` не сделали). SqlServer сделает откат такой транзакции, при разрыве соединения. Запросив затем данные из таблицы в новом соединении, мы увидим, что она пустая.

Также автоматический `ROLLBACK` может происходить при возникновении ошибок (таких как, например, нарушение PK, FK ограничений при вставке или удалении данных), если включена опция [XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188792.aspx) (по умолчанию `OFF`). Например:

```
set xact_abort on;
begin tran;
insert into test (id) values (2);
select * from test;
insert into test (id) values (2); --error: Violation of PK ...
select * from test;
commit tran;
```

в этом случае до второго `select` и до `commit` дело не дойдёт, и откат произойдёт автоматически. Теперь при выключенном `xact_abort` (то что по умолчанию):

```
set xact_abort off;
begin tran;
insert into test (id) values (3);
insert into test (id) values (3); -- error
insert into test (id) values (4);
commit tran;
select * from test;
```

Несмотря на ошибку дело дойдёт и до `commit` (соответственно отката не будет) и до `select` после него.

К сожалению опция `set xact_abort on` полезна далеко не всегда. В частности она не откатывает транзакцию при генерации пользовательских исключений (в том числе сгенерированных в DML-триггерах). Например:

```
set xact_abort on;
begin tran;
insert into test (id) values (5);
if not exists (select 1 from test where id = 0)
    raiserror('Bad data', 16, 1);
commit tran;
select * from test;
```

Несмотря на `set xact_abort on` и сгенерированное исключение дело дойдёт и до `commit` и до `select` после него. Поэтому полезнее может быть целенаправленный вызов `rollback`.

```
-- вернули опцию в состояние по-умолчанию, если она была оставлена в состоянии ON
set xact_abort off;
```

**Управляемый ROLLBACK**

Часто применяется в `catch` блоке, при оборачивании транзакции в `try ... catch ...` конструкцию:

```
begin try
    begin tran;
    -- тут делаем что-то
    commit tran;
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran;
end catch
```

При `xact_abort off` (т.е. по умолчанию) `ROLLBACK` не происходит автоматически, если транзакция была открыта, но из-за ошибки не достигла `COMMIT`. В этом случае SqlServer позволяет программисту самому решить будет ли откат полезен при той или иной ошибке, или нет. Далее пара примеров, когда откат может быть полезен в `catch` и когда вреден.

**Пример 1:** Изменение данных в транзакции.

Пусть есть процедура, которая в транзакции делает вставку данных в две связанных таблицы:

```
create procedure dbo.SetUserInfo
(
    @uid uniqueidentifier = NULL,
    @info xml
)
as
begin try
    set nocount, xact_abort on;

    if @info is NULL or @info.exist('/User') = 0
    begin
        raiserror('No or bad data provided.', 16, 1);
        return;
    end;

    begin transaction;

    declare @inserted table (ID int not NULL);
    declare @id int;

    merge into dbo.Users t
    using(
        select
            @uid,
            @info.value('(/User/@FirstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
            @info.value('(/User/@LastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
        ) s(UID, FirstName, LastName)
    on t.UID = s.UID
    when matched then
        update
        set t.FirstName = s.FirstName, t.LastName = s.LastName
    when not matched then
        insert (UID, FirstName, LastName)
        values (s.UID, s.FirstName, s.LastName)
    output inserted.ID into @inserted (ID)
        ;

    select @id = ID from @inserted;

    merge into dbo.UserContacts t
    using (
        select @id, ct.ID, x.c.value('@Value', 'nvarchar(400)')
        from @info.nodes('/User[1]/Contacts[1]/Contact') x(c)
            join dbo.UserContactTypes ct on ct.Type = x.c.value('@Type', 'nvarchar(400)')
    ) s (UserID, ContactTypeID, ContactInfo)
    on t.UserID = s.UserID and t.ContactTypeID = s.ContactTypeID
    when not matched by source then
        delete
    when matched then
        update
        set t.ContactInfo = s.ContactInfo
    when not matched then
        insert (UserID, ContactTypeID, ContactInfo)
        values (s.UserID, s.ContactTypeID, s.ContactInfo)
        ;

    commit transaction;

end try
begin catch
    declare
        @errMsg nvarchar(4000) = error_message(),
        @errLine int = error_line(),
        @procName sysname = quotename(object_schema_name(@@procid)) + '.' + quotename(object_name(@@procid))
        ;

    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback transaction;

    raiserror('%s in %s at %d', 16, 1, @errMsg, @procName, @errLine);
end catch
GO
```

Допустим теперь, что произошёл вызов процедуры и началась вставка данных. Предположим, что вставка в `Users` прошла успешно, а при вставке в `UserContacts` произошел конфликт с уникальным индексом `(UserID, ContactTypeID)` (из-за того, например, что в `@info` один и тот же `<Contact Type="Phone" Value="0(000)000-00-00" />` затесался дважды).

Если логикой приложения продиктовано, что либо сущность вставляется целиком, либо вообще не вставляется - тогда в `catch` делается `rollback` (как в данном примере).

Но возможны ситуации, когда ошибки, возникшие в результате выполнения каких-то отдельных запросов, не являются серьёзным основанием для отката всех совершенных действий. Например, если у нас не две связанных таблицы, а импорт данных в несколько независимых таблиц, и мы не хотим откатывать ту часть данных, что была уже успешно внесена. Тогда в `catch` можно попытаться сделать `commit` (не любая ошибка сделает это возможным, о том как это сделать корректно - в следующем примере).

Т.е. `rollback` не обязан происходить при возникновении любой ошибки. Делать откат, или нет - зависит от семантики данных и логики приложения.

**Пример 2**: Чтение данных в транзакции.

Транзакции для изменения данных достаточно привычны, но иногда в транзакции нуждается и чтение. Для таких транзакций необдуманно вызванный `rollback` может оказать медвежью услугу.

Пусть есть процедура, которая в `repeatable read` или `snapshot` транзакции читает данные:

```
create procedure dbo.GetSalesData
(
    @dateFrom datetime,
    @dateTo datetime
)
as
begin try
    set nocount on;

    declare @userID int;
    select @userID = UserID from #Session;

    if @userID is NULL
    begin
        raiserror('Access denied.', 16, 1);
        return;
    end;

    create table #Orders (OrderID int not NULL);
    alter table #Orders add primary key (OrderID);

    set transaction isolation level snapshot;
    begin transaction;

    insert into #Orders (OrderID)
    select op.OrderID
    from dbo.OrderPermissions(@userID) op
        join dbo.Orders ord on ord.ID = op.OrderID
    where op.[Permissions] > 0
        and ord.[Date] >= @dateFrom and ord.[Date] < @dateTo

    -- some check based on #Order and other data
    if exists (select 1 from #Orders o join ... where ...)
    begin
        raiserror('Check fail.', 16, 1);
        return;
    end;

    select ...
    from dbo.Orders ord
        join #Orders o on o.OrderID = ord.ID

    select ...
    from dbo.Invoices inv
        join #Orders o on o.OrderID = inv.OrderID

    select ...
    from dbo.Shipment sh
        join #Orders o on o.OrderID = sh.OrderID

    commit transaction;

end try
begin catch
    declare
        @errMsg nvarchar(4000) = error_message(),
        @errLine int = error_line(),
        @procName sysname = quotename(object_schema_name(@@procid)) + '.' + quotename(object_name(@@procid))
        ;

    if xact_state() = 1
        commit transaction;
    else if xact_state() = -1
        rollback transaction;

    raiserror('%s in %s at %d', 16, 1, @errMsg, @procName, @errLine);
end catch
GO
```

В процедуре происходит следующее. Открывается транзакция. В ней заполняется фильтрующая таблица `#Orders` (чтобы потом дать пользователю только то, что ему разрешено видеть). Затем некоторая проверка на основании `#Orders` и других данных. Если проверка проходит, то данные отдаются, если нет - генерируется ошибка.

Предположим, что эта проверка не была успешной. Открыта транзакция и произошла ошибка `raiserror('Check fail.', 16, 1)`, вследствие чего управление передаётся в `catch`. Должен ли в `catch` произойти `rollback`? Нет. Ведь мы только читаем данные и ничего не изменяем (кроме временной таблицы `#Orders`). Более того, таблица `#Orders` создана до входа в транзакцию, а заполнялась в транзакции. Вследствие чего, если бы мы стали делать `rollback` начал бы происходить откат вставленных в неё данных, а это дольше, чем `commit` и простое уничтожение `#Orders` при выходе из процедуры. Т.е. в данном случае в `catch` лучше попытаться сделать `commit`, возможность или невозможность которого определяется функцией [XACT_STATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189797.aspx).

Comment: А использование переменной @@Error вместо Try/Catch правильно? Просто, не вижу этого в примерах.

Comment: @iluxa1810, добавил про `@@error` в начало.

Comment: а если после каждого упдейта стоит IF @@ERROR <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN?

Comment: @xSx, можно, по-идее, но я бы не стал так делать (дублирование кода), плюс нужно возврат или переход делать вручную, иначе исполнение дальше продолжится